# Poincare type inequality on compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a Poincare Inequality on balls but instead of euclidean space, I have a compact manifold with or without boundary. The inequality I am looking for is the equivalent of

$ \int_{B_{r}(x)} |f(y) - f(z)|^{p} dy \leq c r^{n+p-1} \int_{B_{r}(x)} |Df(y)|^{p} |y-z|^{1-n} dy$ 
where $f \in C^{1}(B_{r}(x))$ and $z \in B_{r}(x)$

I was looking at some sources but what I could find is a global inequality where only the function $f(y)$ itself is bounded by the derivative not $f(y)-f(z)$. If you can point me to a source, where I could find such an inequality, I would be grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can always add constants without changing the derivative, be it the Euclidean space or the compact manifold, so the offset by the value at some point (or the mean over the ball, or whatever else killing the constant terms) is inevitable on the left hand side.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think the global one had the function in $W^{1,p}$. But anyway, I was wondering if the above inequality is true on a compact Riemannian manifold  with or without boundary.

Answer (score 1):

(This is just a comment without too many details, and I'm not sure whether it will help you, but it is too long to fit into a comment, so I used the answer field)

If you want to do something like that on a manifold, then you need to say what $|.|$ is, i.e. you need a metric, so you are probably referring to Riemannian manifolds. If you have a compact Riemannian manifold, then in suitable local charts the metric can be bounded from below and from above by the Euclidean metric, i.e. $$ g(v,v) \le C \langle v, v\rangle \le C^\prime g(v, v)$$
If you choose geodesic coordinate neighbourhoods you have, in addition, radial isometries, which allows to retain the radial growth in the inequalities. So, unless you are picky about the constant $c$ appearing in your inequality's right hand side, you get the desired inequality on the manifold simply by adapting the Euclidean ones, using well known techniques from Riemannian geometry.

As a side remark, a global $L^p$ bound for $f$ by $Df$ cannot be true since (on compact $M$) you can always add an arbitrary constant to $f$ without changing the derivative and without getting something which is not integrable, but you can increase the $L^p$ norm as much as you like. You need a bound at least at some fixed point.